# Drag and Drop Jquery drop the object to box

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm doing a simple drag and drop application. But what I want to accomplish is drag the object (100px by 100px) to box (500px by 500px), while I drop it inside box, when I drag it once again, it should not go beyond the box, but it is only draggable in any area of the box.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<style>
#makeMeDraggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: green; }
#makeMeDroppable { float: left; margin: 50px; width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 1px     solid #999; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$( init );
function init() {
$('#makeMeDraggable').draggable();
$('#makeMeDroppable').droppable( {
drop: handleDropEvent
} );
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

 <div id="content" style="height: 400px;">

   <div id="makeMeDraggable"> </div>
   <div id="makeMeDroppable"> </div>

 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

But it's not doing what I want. Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the draggable's [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option, activated when dropped on the droppable:

```
$(init);
function init() {
    $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable();
    $('#makeMeDroppable').droppable({
        drop: function () {
            $("#makeMeDraggable").draggable("option", "containment", "#makeMeDroppable");
        }
    });
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t9Lzb/)**